# Android - Bottom Sheet peekview hidden

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

As said in the title, I have a problem with my bottom sheet.

What I want in my bottom sheet is a RecyclerView with dynamic items that can change anytime. There is also components before and after the RecyclerView. For convenience, I put a fragment in the bottom sheet.

Here is my bottom sheet :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bsControllers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/controllerPeekHeight"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flBsContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And here is my Fragment :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/clControllerSheetRoot"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="fr.mld.dmg.view.fragment.ControllerSheetFragment">

<View
    android:id="@+id/vPeek"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/controllerPeekHeight"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/green"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbControllerScan"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBle"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_thread_online"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vPeek"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivExpansionIndicator"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vPeek"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvControllerCount"
    style="@style/BoldWhite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivLight"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivBle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vPeek"
    tools:text="3"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLight"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_light_unselected"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvConnected"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvControllerCount"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vPeek"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvConnected"
    style="@style/BoldWhite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/connected"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivExpansionIndicator"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivLight"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vPeek"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvControllers"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bConnectAll"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vPeek"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bConnectAll"
    style="@style/Button.ButtonWhiteStroke"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/connect_all"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bUpdateAll"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bUpdateAll"
    style="@style/Button.ButtonWhiteStroke"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/update_all"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bConnectAll"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/vTagUpdate"
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tag_warning"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bUpdateAll"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bUpdateAll"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My problem**

On first launch, the bottom sheet is scrolled down by the peek height. When I expand it then collapse it, it isn't scrolled down by the peek height. Also, it happens only when my RecyclerView has too much items to fit in the screen height, otherwise it works just fine.

**What I already tried**

- I tried to put the NestedScrollView inside the Fragment. Still scrolled down by the peek height.
- I tried to make the NestedScrollView scroll with nestedscrollview.scrollTo(0,0). Doesn't change a thing.
- I tried to remove completely the NestedScrollView. The RecyclerView overlaps the component before and after it.

I'm really lost here and I really don't know what to do anymore. Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
A video to be more clear about my problem :
https://youtu.be/y8KhKW9KS_E

Comment: how much does it collapse to ? in case of large recycler list ??

Comment: @Santanu Sur It isn't collapsed, it is scrolled down by the peek height (56dp) and yes it only occurs when the recycler list is large.

Comment: Scrolling down means getting collapsed !! `56dp` is your peek height ryt ?

Comment: Yes 56dp is the peek height. I'm not sure i'm clear on the "scrolled down" thing. What I mean is that the peek height is always 56dp, but the view inside is scrolled down by the same amount. When I expand then collapse the bottom sheet, it isn't scrolled anymore. Is that better ?

Comment: Have you tried using [ScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)) when using the ScrollView?

Comment: @JuanGonzálezSalinas Yes I did.

Comment: @Kazuya `it isnt scrolled anymore` what do you mean by this ? it should be till 56dp only

Comment: @SantanuSur I'll try to make a video to be more clear.

Comment: @Kazuya cool go for it !! :)

Comment: @SantanuSur I updated my question with a video :)

Comment: saw it but is the green top part which is visible your issue? @Kazuya

Comment: @SantanuSur Yes. I is supposed to be visible as soon as the bottom sheet's Fragment is visible to the user. But on first launch, it is not.

Comment: i cant see the `connectAll` button

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Is it that the `RecyclerView` is scrolled down by the peek height at the start or that, when expanded then collapsed, the `RecyclerView` is no longer scrolled down? When should the top green view appear? When should the `RecyclerView` scroll?

Comment: @Cheticamp It's the NestedScrollView that is scrolled down by the peek height at start and then behave correctly. But it only happens when the RecyclerView has too much items to show them all at once.

Comment: So, at the start, you want the green view to show. After that, everything works as you expect. Is that right?

Comment: @Cheticamp Yes it is.

Comment: Try setting the layout height of the `FrameLayout`, `NestedScrollView` and `ConstraintLayout` to `match_parent` to see if that does any good. You can also try combinations of `match_parent` and `wrap_content`.

Comment: @Cheticamp Following your advice, I finally figured it out. I'll answer to give the solution to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the lead of @Cheticamp, I finally figured where the problem was. At creation, it seems that the RecyclerView is getting focused, causing the NestedScrollView to scroll to the top of it.

All I had to do was to give `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the green background view of my layout. Then, it takes the focus first and doesn't scroll to the top of the RecyclerView.

Many thanks to everyone who helped me figure it out !